# ARIMA model sensitivity

Tags: self-study, categorical-data, arima

Just wondering if a model was sensitive to the overall assumptions made when building the ARIMA model, what would be the impact on the model if any of these assumptions were violated?

Comment: This is a very broad question.  Which assumptions are you most concerned with?

Comment: Additive approach, seasonal factors remain constant, a constant is kept within the ARIMA model when calculating it.